# Transactionscope timeout max is only 10 mins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

I am not able to modify the machine.config on the client

Is there any other way in nested transactions for them to last longer than 10 mins? does isolation level or any other option help in the timeout issue. My transaction within `DoWork()` is fine, I think it is the outer transaction that is timing out.

```
private void DoAllWork()
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout))
    {
        DoWork();
        scope.Complete();   
    }
}
private void  DoWork()
{
    Foreach(Some long running loop)
    {   
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout))
        {
            // Entity Framework queries / modification / Save Changes
            scope.Complete();   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue . you need to change it in machine.config.These setting does not work . But changing machine.config is not good so I solved it like this  .What I am doing is get the transaction Manager object at run time and updating its value and it works for me .

```
   public TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        SetTransactionManagerField("_cachedMaxTimeout", true);
        SetTransactionManagerField("_maximumTimeout", timeout);

          var transactionScopeOptions = new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted,
                Timeout = timeout
            };

        return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transactionScopeOptions);
    }


      private void SetTransactionManagerField(string fieldName, object value)
    {
        typeof(TransactionManager).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, value);
    }
```

And I Use it like this

```
          using (var scope = CreateTransactionScope(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50)))
            {
        // do something 
        scope.Complete();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            new Logger().LogException(e);


        }
```

Comment: is this going to persist the new value forever or is it just valid until the scope.complete()

Comment: hi @mehwish the sample code is to show you if you are done with all your db stuff and want to persist everything you need to set scope.complete unless it will not save .

Comment: its kind of saying that everything is fine so that transaction can finish

Comment: I mean persist the timeout value.. does the new timeout value only exist during the transactionscope or gets written somewhere.

Comment: it will exist during the transaction scope . If you want to persist it then you have to change machine.config  and change the transaction time out . But it is not good practice